# How to open Action Bar when Activity is extending something different

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I am trying to set up the action bar in an Activity which extends fragment:

```
public class ItemDescriptionActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

and this is the fragment:

```
public class ImageSliderFragment extends Fragment
```

How can I set it up, I cannot extend AppCompatActivity, thanks for your help

Comment: you can use toolbar as standalone control

Comment: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

Comment: Thanks @KaranMer I am having a look now

Comment: Thanks I was able do it by the suggestion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `AppCompatActivity` . `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` so you can you fragments inside `AppCompatActivity`.

The class `AppCompatActivity` is a child class of `FragmentActivity`. so you can use AppCompatActivity instead of `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: I don't understand very well, could you give me a small example?

Comment: edited the answer. you can use `public class ItemDescriptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity` in your activity